# Create new column after certain word in R

Tags: regex, r, split

I have columns of data like these:

```
adrs <- data.frame(address=rbind(c("CONFIDENTIST s.r.o. Ul. pri,Panoráme 26 945 01   Komárno"),
                   c("PD Dobrá Niva, a.s. Námestie,SNP 217/2 962 61   Dobrá Niva")))
```

and the desired outcome is:

```
new <- data.frame(rbind(cbind("CONFIDENTIST s.r.o.","Ul. pri,Panoráme 26","945 01","Komárno"),
                  cbind("PD Dobrá Niva, a.s.","Námestie,SNP 217/2","962 61","Dobrá Niva")))
colnames(new) <- c("Name","Street","PSC","Town")
```

More in general: how to split and to create new columns after certain word occuring, in this example: after `s.r.o.` or `a.s`.

Comment: You'll probably want to look into regular expressions, but that is a very difficult task based on your limited test data. You need to be very explicit about the breaking rules. You need to be very, very clear as to what to look for in the text to create breaks.

Comment: Sure, this is what I'm straggling with, how to define the breaking rules. First would be after the words "a.s" and "s.r.o" and also possible the "962 61" reocurring.

Comment: Well, that's not something we can do for you. You need to know that about your data. If your rule is only "split after s.r.o or a.s." then that's fine. But your sample data has other splits. You would need to know every possible word you want to split on or the patter of letters/numbers you want to split on.

Comment: Yes, I thought small demonstration (not complete solution) would be helpful as to get idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's now i might split after `s.r.o.` or `a.s.`

```
strsplit(gsub("(.*(?:s\\.r\\.o\\.|a\\.s\\.))\\s+(.*)","\\1;\\2",adrs$address),";")
```

Comment: And if I make more assumptions about your two sample rows and output data, this may even be a more complete version: `strsplit(gsub("(.*(?:s\\.r\\.o\\.|a\\.s\\.))\\s+(.*)\\s+(\\d{3} \\d{2})\\s+(.*)","\\1\n\\2\n\\3\n\\4",adrs$address),"\n")` But that's making a lot of assumptions.